# How do I parse a GeoJSON shapefile into a dataset with one row per Feature?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I'm working on a project and need to parse a GeoJSON shapefile of flight route airspace in the US. The data is coming from the FAA open data portal: https://adds-faa.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/faa::route-airspace/about

There seems to be some relevant documentation at /workspace/documentation/product/geospatial-docs/vector_data_in_transforms where it mentions:

```
A typical Foundry Ontology pipeline for geospatial vector data may include the following steps:
- Convert into rows with GeoJSON representation of the shape for each feature.
```

However there isn't actually any guidance on how to go about doing this when the source is a single GeoJSON file with a FeatureCollection and the desired output is a dataset with one row per Feature in the collection.

Anyone have a code snippet for accomplishing this? Seems like a pretty generic task in Foundry.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do something like this:

```python
import json

with open('Route_Airspace.geojson', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

rows = []
for feature in data['features']:
    row = {
        'geometry': json.dumps(feature['geometry']),
        'properties': json.dumps(feature['properties']),
        'id': feature['properties']['OBJECTID']
    }
    rows.append(row)
```

Note you can leave out the `properties`, but I like to keep them in this step in case I need them later. Also note this is a good place to set each row's primary key as well (the `Feature`s in this dataset have an `OBJECTID` property, but this may vary)

This `rows` list can then be used to initialise a Pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

or a Spark dataframe (*assuming you're doing this within a transform):

```
df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(rows)
```

The resulting dataframes will have one row per `Feature`, where that feature's shape is contained within the `geometry` column.

Full example within transform:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
import json

@transform(
    out=Output('Path/to/output'),
    source_df=Input('Path/to/source'),
)
def compute(source_df, out, ctx)
    with source_df.filesystem().open('Route_Airspace.geojson', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    rows = []
    for feature in data['features']:
        row = {
            'geometry': json.dumps(feature['geometry']),
            'properties': json.dumps(feature['properties']),
            'id': feature['properties']['OBJECTID']
        }
        rows.append(row)
    
    df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(rows)

    out.write_dataframe(df)
```

Note that for this to work your GeoJSON file needs to be uploaded into a "dataset without a schema" so the raw file becomes accessible via the [FileSystem](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/transforms-python-api-classes/#filesystem) API.

Comment: There is also a library of tools designed for parsing and otherwise transforming geospatial data in Foundry; search the in-platform documentation for `geospatial_tools` for more details. This includes a utility that _slightly_ simplifies the code example above.